# I purchased a number in twilio. How do I forward calls and texts to my phone?

Tags: twilio

I purchased a number in twilio. How do I forward calls and texts to my phone? I'm not a developer, so any simple method or step-by-step instructions are appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sara, a single search turned up a several guide with several approaches (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding). I'm afraid Twilio is a developer centric system though, if you're not a developer and don't have an interest in learning then it might be best to use a different system or approach someone who is willing to do it for you :) The guides on Twilio's documentation are pretty good though and should be enough for anyone I think.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can do that with [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio)! More details [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015962887-Forward-Incoming-SMS-Messages-with-Twilio-Studio), but in short, to forward messages:

1. Access the Studio Dashboard in your Studio [Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/dashboard).
2. Make a new Studio flow by clicking the + sign.
3. Pick a name for your flow and click "next".
   [image]"
4. Click "Start from scratch" followed by Next".
   [image]
5. From the "Widget Library" on the right, drag and drop a "Send Message" widget into the flow.
   [image]
6. Click and drag the "Trigger" widget’s "Incoming Message" lead to connect it to the "Send Message" widget.

[image]

7. Click the "Send Message" widget to show the widget's options on the right. Type in the MESSAGE BODY field:

[image]

8. Under the SEND MESSAGE widget options, scroll down to click to expand MESSAGING & CHAT CONFIG. Type in the desired destination (number to forward to with E.164 formatting) in the `SEND MESSAGE TO` field, and then click `Save`.

[image]

9. Select "Publish".

To activate the Studio flow:

1. Visit the Active Numbers page in your [Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming).
2. Select the phone number you want to edit.
3. Scroll to the `Voice & Fax` section to modify the phone number’s routing like so:

[image]

4. Select "Save".

To forward calls, it'd be similar: for the Studio "Trigger" widget’s "Incoming Call" lead, it should connect it to the "Send Call" widget.

Let me know if this helps! <3 :D